# "language" attribute on Rails ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, lazy-loading

I'll try to figure out some strange behaviour from a ActiveRecord model. The model have a `language` field, which is filled with a language identifier ("de", "en")

If I want to access the language attribute from the from a model object, I'll get `nil`.

```
 $> foo = Product.first
 => #<Product id: 1049488, ... , language: "en", ...>

 $> foo.id
 => 1049488

 $> foo.language
 => nil

 $> foo.send("language")
 => nil

 $> foo.to_yaml
 => "--- !ruby/object:Product \nattributes: \n  ... language: en\n ..."

 $> foo.language
 => "en"
```

It seems like a hidden lazy loading "feature" or something else is trying to interventing here. Is it the field name "language" which causes this behaviour or is there some other mechanism which I dont understand?

I use the following Gems inside my Rails project:

- rails 3.0.0
- jquery-rails
- sqlite3-ruby
- mysql
- rmagick
- acts_as_tree
- dbi
- dbd-odbc
- solr-ruby
- progressbar

I've also checked various "[reserved words](http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/)" list for collisions but no list has `language` on it. When the column name will be changed to `lang`, everything works fine. So, it *is* a naming problem, but I can't track it down. Are there any tools to get a call-stack or something else from a given method in Ruby to locate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby application often starts to behave strange or weird if you have a **name conflict**. Maybe it is some kind of reserved word, or a conflict between a column and a method name. Do you have anything else which is named `language` in your model or in your plugins?

Comment: No, there is no other method with the name `language` in the model or in any of the installed plugins. I've add the used gems to my question.